# Parámetros en C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> /*Se importa libreria util para el compilador*/
#define PI 3,141596 /* se establece una variable global*/

float procesar(float radio); /*NO ENTIENDO LA LOGICA DE ESTA
FUNCIÓN*/

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...

    float radio, area;

    printf("radio = ");
    scanf("%f", &radio); /* se almacena el valor */

    area = procesar(radio);
    printf("area = %f", area);
}

float procesar(float r){ /* r representa el valor del radio proporcionado desde main*/
    /*Tampoco entiendo como r es el valor proporcionado desde main*/
    float a;
    a = PI * r * r;
    return (a); /* es el valor que devuelve a main*/
}
```

Estoy empezando a aprender a programar de manera autodidacta y no entiendo este programa de un libro. Si alguien me podría explicar, lo agradecería. En resumen, me lío un poco con los parámetros y cómo otras funciones los usan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

es un gusto sabes que aprenderás a programar, antes que nada, te aconsejaría que vieras videos en YouTube de programación desde cero. Ya que si empiezas viendo código de otros autores te vas a enredar muchísimo.
Bueno, te explico: `float procesar(float r)` es un método Parametrico, quiere decir que esta función obtendrá un valor de tipo float (float es un tipo de dato).

```
float radio, area; //Aquí esta declarando variables de tipo float 

printf("radio = "); //esta pidiendo a el usuario que ingrese un numero ( en este caso el radio)
scanf("%f", &radio); /* se almacena el valor *//radio va a almacenar el valor que el usuario de.

area = procesar(radio); //Aquí esta asignándole un valor al tipo de dato Area, el valor se optendra del metodo paramétrico, ósea, procesar(radio) quiere decir que el dato que introdujo el usuario lo esta mandando a el método y este método regresara un valor que se almacenara en el dato Area.
printf("area = %f", area); // Aquí solamente está mostrándole al usuario el resultado de la operación que hizo el método paramétrico.
```

Ahora bien, el método:

```
 float procesar(float r){ //Float r es donde se almacena la variable (en este caso seria EL DATO QUE EL USUARIO ESCRIBIO), se mando a llamar en el main el método, el cual llevaba un valor, el valor se almacena en el ti po de dato float, el cual se declara en el método paramétrico.

float a; //aquí se declara otra variable de tipo float, para recibir el valor que de resultado la siguiente operacion

a = PI * r * r; //Aquí menciona la ecuación que hará. 
return (a); return (a) significa que el resultado lo esta mandando de vuelta al main, para que se muestre al usuario el resultado.
```

Ejemplo:

```
printf("radio = "); //YO ESCRIBO 5

scanf("%f", &radio); //Aquí se guardo el 5 que meti

area = procesar(radio); //Aquí se vería de esta manera procesar(5);
printf("area = %f", area); //me devolverá el resultado del método el cual quedaría asi: printf("area = %f", 78.5399);
```

El método:

```
float procesar(float r) //se vería asi float procesar(5)
float a; //aun no tiene valor, solo esta declarado.
a = PI * r * r; //Aquí se vería asi: a= 3.141596*5*5;
return(a); se vería de esta manera: return(78.5399‬);
```

el 78.5399 es el resultado el cual se le mostrara al usuario

Espero haberte explicado de la mejor manera.

Comment: No responden pero si dan -1 ... doble morales. que no sepa como editar la respuesta para que se vea agradable es otra cosa muy diferente a que no sea la respuesta correcta.

Comment: Ignoro quien te ha puesto el negativo... pero tu respuesta no explica cómo pasa el valor de la variable del `main` a la función. Imagino que irán por ahí los tiros

Answer (score 3):

> `float procesar(float radio); /*NO ENTIENDO LA LOGICA DE STA
>   FUNCIÓN*/`

Vamos a ver un ejemplo sencillo:

```
int func(int value1, int value2)
{
    return value1 * value2;
}
```

Al compilar esta función con optimizaciones para un AMD o INTEL de 64 bits, se generará un ensamblado como el siguiente:

```
mov     eax, edi
imul    eax, esi
ret
```

Sin embargo, esta otra versión:

```
int func(int value1, short value2)
{
    return value1 * value2;
}
```

Genera, en las mismas condiciones, el siguiente ensamblado:

```
movsx   eax, si
imul    eax, edi
ret
```

¿Ves la diferencia? Esta versión utiliza otros registros para trabajar.

Vale, ahora vamos al otro lado... imagínate que el compilador se encuentra esto:

```
int var1;
short var2;

func(var1, var2);
```

Si no conocemos el prototipo de la función? ¿Qué hacemos aquí?

- ¿Asumimos que existirá una función `func(int, short)`?
- ¿Asuminos que existirá una función `func(int, int)`?
- ¿Asumimos otro caso diferente?

El problema es que si nos confundimos le entregaremos valores a la función donde no los espera, luego el resultado que obtendremos será incorrecto.

Así pues, no podemos dejar nada a la imaginación, el compilador necesita saber cual es la firma de la función para poder colocar los valores donde realmente los va a recibir la función.

¿Y cómo puede el compilador *conocer* la firma de la función?

Pues hay dos maneras:

- O implementamos la función antes de su uso (con antes me refiero a físicamente en el archivo de código)
- Aportamos la declaración de la función.

Como al compilador realmente la implementación no le importa en este paso nos basta con la declaración. Es por eso que se acostumbra a dejar las declaraciones de las funciones en los archivos de cabecera, apartándolas de las respectivas implementaciones.

> `/*Tampoco entiendo como r es el valor promocionado desde main*/`

Como ha visto los valores no se promocionan... simplemente se hace una copia de los mismos. La función se limita a usar esas copias y, al finalizar la función, dichas copias se descartan (su espacio pasa a estar disponible para almacenar otros valores).

C es un lenguaje de bajo nivel, luego está muy ligado al ensamblador y eso se ve en detalles como estos que estás preguntando.

Fuente ensamblados: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9cJp6K)

Answer (score 0):

Cuando un programa es compilado en `C`, el compilador recorre línea por línea el código, es por esto que se acostumbra a usar `prototipos` de funciones, esto es para que el compilador no de error en "tiempo de compilación", si tú quitas el prototipo `float procesar(float radio);` cuando el compilador llegue a la línea `area = procesar(radio);` dará error porque la función no está definida sino hasta terminada la función `main`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3,141596 /* se establece una variable global*/

float procesar(float radio); /*Prototipo de la función procesar,
más adelante se define el comportamiento de esta función*/

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...

    float radio, area;

    printf("radio = ");
    scanf("%f", &radio); /* se almacena el valor */

    area = procesar(radio);
    printf("area = %f", area);
}

/*Definición de la función procesar,*/
float procesar(float r){
    float a;
    a = PI * r * r;
    return (a); /* es el valor que devuelve a main*/
}
```

Con respecto a como `r` es "proporcionado" por la función `main` es bastante simple, y es cuando se hace `area = procesar(radio);` ya que se le estaría pasando a la función `procesar` el valor de `r` por valor, el valor de `radio` sería el valor de `r` que la función `procesar` manejaría internamente.

Comment: muchas gracias ahora si lo entiendo, esto como se le conoce en este lenguajes decir esta manera de usar las funciones, lo digo porque hace 4 aprendi algo de Python y el cual las recordaba de otra menta, ojo hace que no escribo código desde que deje de programar cuando tenia 16 y he vuelto ahora con 20,

Comment: Se le llama `prototípo de función`, [aquí](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/importance-of-function-prototype-in-c/) hay más información.

Comment: No entiendo porque le dieron -1 a esta respuesta... Da rabia cuando te dan -1 sin ninguna razón.

Comment: *si tú quitas el prototipo float procesar(float radio); cuando el compilador llegue a la línea area = procesar(radio); dará error ..* No es del todo cierto. Lo usual es que el compilador se invente el prototipo, solo que por defecto el tipo de valor de retorno será `Int`.

Comment: [MrDave1999](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/105299/mrdave1999) gracias ṕor la info.

Answer (score -1):

Esta es la definición de una función

> Una función es un conjunto de líneas de código que realizan una tarea
>   específica y puede retornar un valor. Las funciones pueden tomar
>   parámetros que modifiquen su funcionamiento. Las funciones pueden retornar parámetros / valores / resultados.

Simplemente la utilidad de una función es para reducir, organizar y reutilizar código.

La declaración de una función es algo que se pueda entender y sea general para cualquier caso (reutilizable).

En este caso la función `procesar(float r)` tiene como finalidad una acción (hacer un calculo). Para ello esta a la espera de ser utilizada (que es donde la estas usando en tu main).

```
float procesar(float r) { // aquí tu variable r, es solo un nombre y no representa nada en particular
    // esta variable r sirve para ser sustituida por un valor (como lo haces desde tu main) 
    // se entendería que r es igual a radio r = radio, es simplemente una sustitución de valores
    float a;
    a = PI * r * r;
    return (a);
}
```

Si tu no ocuparas el uso de las funciones tu código quedaría de esta forma

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...

    float radio, area;

    printf("radio = ");
    scanf("%f", &radio); /* se almacena el valor */

    area = PI * radio * radio;
    printf("area = %f", area);
}
```

Posiblemente no veas del todo el funcionamiento de las funciones porque es un proceso pequeño, pero si tuvieras que realizar mas operaciones y las tuvieras que repetir N número de veces te quedaría un código muy extenso.